# I'm looking for Tabs similar to my given image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create tabs similar to this - https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdBi0.jpg

After searching on web I found code for the tabs. I am facing the problem to design it according to the above screenshot.

I want to create a full width tab with a static content on the right side. If you check the screenshot, There is full width border on top and bottom of the tabs.

In the screenshot, on the right side there is "rewards" section, I want it something like that to remain even if the user click on different tabs.

Here's my code

```css
@import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700");
@import url("http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.css");


main {
  min-width: 320px;
  max-width: 800px;
  padding: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #fff;
}

section {
  display: none;
  padding: 20px 0 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}

input {
  display: none;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0 -1px;
  padding: 11px 11px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #878585;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

label:before {
  font-family: fontawesome;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

label[for*='1']:before {
  content: '\f040';
}

label[for*='2']:before {
  content: '\f27b';
}

label[for*='3']:before {
  content: '\f003';
}

label:hover {
  color: #888;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input:checked + label {
  color: #252424;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-top: 2px solid #ed1c24;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

#tab1:checked ~ #content1,
#tab2:checked ~ #content2,
#tab3:checked ~ #content3,
#tab4:checked ~ #content4 {
  display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
  label {
    font-size: 15px;
  }

  label:before {
    margin: 5px;
    font-size: 15px;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  label {
    padding: 15px;
  }
}
```

```html
 <input id="tab1" type="radio" name="tabs" checked>
  <label for="tab1">Campaign</label>
    
  <input id="tab2" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab2">Comments</label>
    
  <input id="tab3" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab3">Contact</label>
    
  <section id="content1">
    <h2>
      Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet beef venison beef ribs kielbasa. Sausage pig leberkas, t-bone sirloin shoulder bresaola. Frankfurter rump porchetta ham. Pork belly prosciutto brisket meatloaf short ribs.
    </h2>
    <p>
      Brisket meatball turkey short loin boudin leberkas meatloaf chuck andouille pork loin pastrami spare ribs pancetta rump. Frankfurter corned beef beef tenderloin short loin meatloaf swine ground round venison.
    </p>
  </section>
    
  <section id="content2">
   <p>comments</p>
  </section>
    
  <section id="content3">
    <p>contact</p>
</section>
```

Comment: Unclear what you are asking.

Comment: And your question is..?

Comment: Sorry If I am unclear. I want to make tabs something like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/KdBi0.jpg

Comment: Please, if you include external resources, then insert them in the main post, so you avoid link rot

Comment: Actually you are looking for Tabs UI  similar to your given image.

Comment: @Marcos Pérez Gude: Actually "op" looking for Tabs UI similar to his proved image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want this ? considering your image.
Just added as per your requirement. just added `one parent` to both `tab div` and `right side content div` and applied css as you want. Hope it helps you. Thanks.

```css
@import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700");
@import url("http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.css");


main {
  min-width: 320px;
  max-width: 800px;
  padding: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #fff;
}

section {
  display: none;
  padding: 20px 0 0;
  border-top:1px solid #eee;
}

input {
  display: none;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0 -1px;
  padding: 11px 11px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #878585;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

label:before {
  font-family: fontawesome;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

label[for*='1']:before {
  content: '\f040';
}

label[for*='2']:before {
  content: '\f27b';
}

label[for*='3']:before {
  content: '\f003';
}

label:hover {
  color: #888;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input:checked + label {
  color: #252424;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #29DE75
}

#tab1:checked ~ #content1,
#tab2:checked ~ #content2,
#tab3:checked ~ #content3,
#tab4:checked ~ #content4 {
  display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
  label {
    font-size: 15px;
  }

  label:before {
    margin: 5px;
    font-size: 15px;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  label {
    padding: 15px;
  }
}
.parent{
  width:100%;
}
.child{
  width:60%;
  float:left;
}
.side-content{
     width: 30%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 75px 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  <input id="tab1" type="radio" name="tabs" checked>
  <label for="tab1">Campaign</label>
    
  <input id="tab2" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab2">Comments</label>
    
  <input id="tab3" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab3">Contact</label>
    
  <section id="content1">
    <h2>
      Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet beef venison beef ribs kielbasa. Sausage pig leberkas, t-bone sirloin shoulder bresaola. Frankfurter rump porchetta ham. Pork belly prosciutto brisket meatloaf short ribs.
    </h2>
    <p>
      Brisket meatball turkey short loin boudin leberkas meatloaf chuck andouille pork loin pastrami spare ribs pancetta rump. Frankfurter corned beef beef tenderloin short loin meatloaf swine ground round venison.
    </p>
  </section>
    
  <section id="content2">
   <p>comments</p>
  </section>
    
  <section id="content3">
    <p>contact</p>
</section>
  </div>

<div class="side-content">
    <p>kielbasa. Sausage pig leberkas, t-bone sirloin shoulder bresaola. Frankfurter rump porchetta ham. Pork belly prosciutt</p>
  </div>
  
  </div>
```

Comment: Not exactly. I want some content on the right side of the tabs that remain static even if the user change tabs and also a full width border on top and bottom of the tabs

Comment: @Sagar, Give some explanation to "OP" what you have did, because we are not doing services like writing code at StackOverflow.

Comment: so you can make another div outside the tab div. wait let me edit

Comment: @SayedRafeeq ya bro..i am editing now with explanation.